# Why does my cloth simulation bounce for a moment before settling down?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Whenever I play/try to render an animation with cloth simulation active it bounces for a second before settling down. Is there a way to effectively start rendering the animation from a point where it has settled and reacts to the models movement normally? The only thing I can think of is to add a couple of seconds to the animation before it starts to give it time to settle but that would increase the render time significantly.

Comment: That would work fine. Consider also that you don't need to render those frames before the cloth simulation settles . You can modify the range of frames to be rendered, so that the first rendered frame occurs once the bouncing has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You are right with the idea of starting the simulation before the start of the animation so that the first rendered frame uses a stationary version of the cloth.

Note that this will have no effect on your render times, the simulation only needs to be [baked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html) once before you start rendering and the cached results are then used during render.